# Enable Kubernetes feature gates with Tectonic

Tags: kubernetes, tectonic-coreos

I must deploy a kubernetes cluster with [tectonic](https://coreos.com/tectonic/) for a client and I need a kuberenetes feature gate enabled, is that possible?

needed feature gate: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/

needed for: https://www.arangodb.com/2018/03/arangodb-operator-kubernetes-stateful-cluster-deployments/

Kubernetes version: 1.9.6 (as provided by 1.9.6-tectonic.1)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to enable feature gate for using local-storage in kubernetes cluster after kubernetes 1.10.

You can directly use `local-storage` same as any other storage class.

Please have a look at my following answer, how to setup `local-storage` PV, PVC in kubernetes.

EDIT: As you're on kubernetes 1.9, you can do it this way:

You need to provide the feature-gates while starting the cluster using `kubeadm init --config=config.yaml` to `apiserver`, `controller-manager` and `scheduler`. Please refer following config:

```
 apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
 kind: MasterConfiguration
 apiServerExtraArgs:
   service-node-port-range: 80-32767
   feature-gates: "PersistentLocalVolumes=true,VolumeScheduling=true,MountPropagation=true"
 controllerManagerExtraArgs:
   feature-gates: "PersistentLocalVolumes=true,VolumeScheduling=true,MountPropagation=true"
 schedulerExtraArgs:
   feature-gates: "PersistentLocalVolumes=true,VolumeScheduling=true,MountPropagation=true"
```

Then you need to create your own storage class, as there is no local-storage class present. So create your own class as follow:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage-data
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Now you can create your PV and PVC in following way:

PV Definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-mariadb-0
  labels:
    pod-name: mariadb-0
  annotations:
    "volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/node-affinity": '{
      "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
        "nodeSelectorTerms": [
          { "matchExpressions": [
              { "key": "kubernetes.io/hostname",
                "operator": "In",
                "values": ["prod-mysql-0"]
              }
          ]}
        ]}}'
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage-data
  local:
    path: /mnt/local-storage/mysql-data-0
```

PVC definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mariadb
  name: mysql-mariadb-0
  namespace: mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage-data
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod-name: mariadb-0
```

> [Is it possible to mount different pods to the same portion of a local persistent volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948124/is-it-possible-to-mount-different-pods-to-the-same-portion-of-a-local-persistent/52952505#52952505)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, unfortunately the latest tectonic version uses only kubernetes version 1.9.6. I will include the version in my question

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this give you brief idea.

Comment: Yes I knew I have to provide the user gates, my problem is how to do this with tectonic. In the files generated by tectonic I don't have anything like "MasterConfiguration", "apiServerExtraArgs" or "feature-gates"