# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "mongo-two": lstat /var/lib/mongo: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am trying to get mongo-replicaset chart working.

Kubelet report this error while mongo-replicaset chart deployment:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "mongo-two": lstat /mongo/data: no such file or directory
```

On each node, /mongo/data folder **exist**, driving me crazy. Note: on nodes, lstat command doesn't exists, but I suspect kubelet container to bring it.?
[image]

I have 3 persistent volumes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-[one/two/three]
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 40Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mongo/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - [one/two/three]
```

StatefulSet yaml: (mongo-replicaset helm chart 3.8.0)

```
...
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data/db
      name: datadir
...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: local-storage
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 40Gi
...
```

Still having "no such directory" on an existing directory..
What's incorrect? I can give additionnal data if needed.

Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem came from kubelet which is containerized (because of Rancher installation)

I add a volume definition into kubelet containers and it's OK.

For those interested by creating persistent local volume in a Rancher - Kubernetes installation, just add this to your cluster yaml in order to kubelet can mount your volume:

```
services:
  kubelet:
    extra_binds:
       - /path_to_mount:/path_to_mount:rshared
```

don't forget the two dot rshared.

Answer (score 0):

In your statefulset, you must be having volume provisioner with `subPath` field. If you remove that `subPath` field from your statefulset yaml file you will not encounter this error.

The issue is there is bug in hostpath volume provisioner that encounters an error with "lstat: no such file or directory" if there is subpath field present in deployment/statefulset, even if the field is empty. This error doesn't let statefulset come up and they goes into containerCreatingConfigErr (happened with me on kubeadm)

For more info you can visit this link

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2256

Comment: I don't have any subpath field in statefulset yaml :(

Comment: okay. I will have a look again. I am using local-storage myself, and if folder is present, I never saw this issue

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the storage-class definition? I copy paste it from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local

Comment: I have defined the local-storage PV and PVC in my following ans:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948124/is-it-possible-to-mount-different-pods-to-the-same-portion-of-a-local-persistent/52952505#52952505

Could you please have a look and try that way

Comment: It seems we have all the same.

Comment: If you look up your PV, it has path `/mongo/data` but you're getting error at `/var/lib/mongo`, are you sure this is the PV you're using? Where are you using `/var/lib/mongo` in your yaml files?

Comment: Thanks you for pointing, it comes from message writing. All my paths (yaml and on nodes) are /mongo/data. I updated my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184867/discussion-between-slim-and-prafull-ladha).